# response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n'

Tags: node.js, performance, passwords, backend

My Node js code is sending proper email on localhost but in backend there showing email and password not valid ?

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


const sendEmail = async (subject, message, send_to, sent_from, reply_to) => {

    // Create Email Transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
        },
    
    });
    // Options for sending email
    const options = {
        from: sent_from,
        to: send_to,
        reply_to: reply_to,
        subject: subject,
        html: message,
    };

    // Check email sent successfully or not
    transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(info);
        }
    });

};



module.exports = sendEmail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host : imap.gmail.com,
    port: 465,
    secure:true,
    auth : {
        user: abc@gmail.com,
        pass: abc,
    },
   
 });
```

Use **imap.gmail.com** as host and use app specific password in your account, the issue might be fixed, for my case it is fixed by changing the host **smtp.gmail.com** to **imap.gmail.com**. Above code is an example of how my issue is fixed.